# Special Relativity problem - proper time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

> Two events as observed from some inertial frame (say $S'$) are separated by a distance of $27.6 × 10^8$ metres and an interval of $11.0$ sec. What is the proper time interval between the two events?

Isn't there a lack of information here? Don't we need the velocity of the $S'$ frame to find gamma?

In the solution they take $v=(27.6×10^8)/11$. Can't $v$ be different and completely independent of those values?

Comment: Hint: Compute the (invariant) spacetime interval first, from there compute the eigentime.

Comment: Yes, using invariant space time interval, you get the answer. But on using this formula
t=gamma(t'-vx'/c^2). You get the answer by substituting v=(27.6×10^8)/11. Is there an intuitive explanation for why velocity is that value?

Comment: Yes, you need to have the velocity $\Delta x/\Delta t$ to be in a frame where the two events have the same position in space.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that:

$$ \Delta s'^2 = (c\Delta t')^2 - (\Delta x')^2 $$

is the same for all reference frames. (I used primes because the problem said it was in $S'$).

If $\Delta s'^2 > 0$, then the events are time-like separated, and there is a frame $S$ in which $\Delta x=0$.

With that:

$$ \Delta s'^2 = \Delta s^2 = (c\Delta t)^2 = (c\Delta \tau)^2 $$

where the last step uses the fact that the word-line between the points is "at-rest", so time is proper time.